# Xcode auto layout orientation changes

Tags: xcode, interface-builder, autolayout

Is it possible to make the following in Xcode's Interface Builder with auto layouts, without writing any code:

[image: Xcode autolayout]

Answer (score 0):

**step1 :** Add 2 views(green and blue) into a stack view and set alignment and distribution as fill.

**step2 :** set height of the blue view as equal to the superview

**step3 :** edit height constraint of the blue view with multiplier 0.6 instaed of 1.0

now the views(blue and green ) will cover the screen with 60 % and 40% respectively

Comment: Thanks for the answer, better late than never - I figured it out almost 5 years ago, I'll see if I can dig up the solution. However your answer is not correct, since it shouldn't fill 60%. The height of the blue should equal the width in portrait mode, and the green should fill the rest.